# Image file path not inserting in database

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-uploading

Here, I am want to insert image path name and want to upload image in a folder.

I am decoding them image using `base64_decode` and want to insert path of image into database. I am also inserting image into a folder.

But nothing is happening. Image is not going in folder and also not inserting image path into database.

Where I am wrong?

Here is my code:

```
$proflepic = "base64 encoded string";

$p_image = base64_decode($proflepic);
                        $im = imagecreatefromstring($p_image);

                        if ($im !== false)
                        {
                            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');    
                            //imagejpeg($im);
                            //imagedestroy($im);

                            $target_dir = "img";

                            $filename = "image_".date('s');

                            $target_file = $target_dir.'/'.$filename;

                            if(!is_dir('../'.$target_dir))
                            {
                                 mkdir('../'.$target_dir);
                            }

                            file_put_contents($filename, $im);

                            $query  = "UPDATE ".$table." SET `profile_pic` '".$target_file."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
                            $result = $db->query($query);
                       }
```

Comment: `echo $query;` chk you query, where u defined this `$table`

Comment: @devpro : I am sure about `$table` and `$id`, that I am getting right.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file_put_contents($target_file, $im);` instead of `$filename`?

Comment: alright, than what are u getting in `echo $query;` ? please share

Comment: ...and check that you have error reporting turned on and check your error log if you're getting any errors.

Comment: `SET \`profile_pic\` '".$target_file."'` should be `SET \`profile_pic\` = '".$target_file."'`. (missing equal sign).

Comment: chk your query as i said, r u missing the = sign as @MagnusEriksson mentioned

Comment: Just silly mistake..!! Thanks for targeting to query. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: But image is not uploading in my folder as I asked in question.

Comment: ...did you look at my first comment? (The third one from the top)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Yes already when you commented but file is not uploading. Should I define any variable?

Comment: Check your error log to see if you actually are getting any errors that might guide you...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : Now I am getting file in my folder, but file is not an image, it is `file type` file not a `jpeg`.

Comment: You're storing the response from `imagecreatefromstring()`, which doesn't return a binary image file, but rather a php image resource. Use `imagejpeg($im, $target_file);` instead of your `file_put_contents()` and you will always get a jpeg. You might want to add _.jpg_ to the target filename as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124970/discussion-between-virb-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: Added an answer. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the end result of what we discussed in the comments, and a couple of other tweaks:

```
$proflepic = "base64 encoded string";
$p_image   = base64_decode($proflepic);
$im        = imagecreatefromstring($p_image);

if ($im !== false)
{
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');    

    $target_dir = "img";
    // Changed to uniqid() instead since date('s') returns seconds,
    // which limits you to 60 images (and the risk of overwriting other images
    // are great). Also added file extension.
    $filename   = "image_" . uniqid() . '.jpg';

    $target_file = $target_dir . '/' . $filename;

    if (!is_dir('../' . $target_dir))
    {
         mkdir('../' . $target_dir);
    }

    // $im is a image resource so let's use imagejpeg() instead
    imagejpeg($im, $target_file);
    imagedestroy($im);

    // Added the missing equal sign
    $query  = "UPDATE ".$table." SET `profile_pic` = '".$target_file."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
}
```